# unconventional time format syntax

Tags: excel, type-conversion

I have an Excel sheet with one column defining time in the following format  3:34'35". In R it is a factor. I would like to convert it to a numeric value. 
Unfortunately ' and "signs prevent me from working with it as a string. Could anybody suggest how to get to recognizable time format or to numeric?

thank you